# How to iterate on hashmap that have k,v of string and list?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> total=new HashMap<>();
```

and now I have hashmap with k,v and I want to iterate and print for each key the key all the values that it have including duplicates, and for each duplicate to print the key again, so it will look like this:

```
123   john

123   tom

123   jack

234   terry

234   jeniffer

345   jacob

555   sara
```

Comment: do include the code that you tried

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan i dont know how to get to the value....i want to get to the value list and iterate on it and i dont know how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : total.entrySet()) {
  for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + s);
  }
}
```

Comment: pls include a null check before iterating the entry.getValue()

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I will leave that to OP. Including such details just obfuscates the point of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed the following setup:

```
    List<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    first.add("a");
    first.add("b");
    List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
    second.add("c");  
    second.add("d");
    HashMap<String, List<String>> total = new HashMap<>();
    total.put("First", first);
    total.put("Second", second);
```

In Java 8, you can use [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) to iterate over the entries of the hashmap and retrieve both key and value in each iteration:

```
    total.forEach( (k, v) -> {
        System.err.printf("%s => %s\n",  k, v);
    });
```

Output:

```
Second => [c, d]
First => [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you could iterate over the entries, then iterate over each list element and print the result:

```
total.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .forEach(entry -> {
        entry.getValue()
        .stream()
        .forEach(string -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + string));
    });
```

Or shorter, but in my eyes less clear:

```
total.forEach((key, list) -> {
    list.forEach(value -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
});
```